# Maven + GAE step-by-step

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I'm looking for a basic tutorial on how to "mavenize" a Google AppEngine project, created by Google Eclipse Plugin.

In case that's too difficult, how to create a Maven project, add GAE support to it then import it into Eclipse and work with the GooglePlugin from there?

P.s. What if I wanted SpringMVC,too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to create maven project from eclipse, but creating it from scratch is very easy. For gae you can use `net.kindleit:maven-gae-plugin` See http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/index.html, it can generate `pom.xml` for you. Or just use it as

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.4</version>
  <configuration>
      <port>8080</port>
      <address>127.0.0.1</address>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>start-gae</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
          <goal>start</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>stop-gae</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but don't forget to add GAE dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and repositories:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
        <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
        <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and then you can generate eclipse config by using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Dev server can be started by `mvn gae:run`, deployment by `mvn gae:deploy`

To use Spring, add dependencies to artifacts `spring-webmvc`, `spring-core` and `spring-context` under group `org.springframework`

Comment: When I type `gae:deploy` I get a message that my authentication credentials could not be found. Could you explain where I need to set them? I am already logged into the Google Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Also eclipse is complaining about the gae plugin execution not being found, how can I solve that one?

Comment: About password see http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/examples/passwordPrompt.html

Comment: Sorry, can't help with Eclipse, i'm not using it